# query with calculated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got table

```
 Manga
 idmanga title idauthor idgenre idmagazine
```

and table

```
 Author
 idauthor name surname
```

How to get table with fields

```
   fullname     title   sumofids
 name+surname          idmanga+idauthor+idgenre+idmagazine
```

I can get fullname like this

```
select name+' '+surname as Fullname from Author
```

But how to get other fields in one query?

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,idmanga)
+CONVERT(VARCHAR,idauthor)
+CONVERT(VARCHAR,idgenre)
+CONVERT(VARCHAR,idmagazine)
```

That should do it all in one string.

Add `+ ' ' +` to put in spaces.

To add all the values together, your query should work to get the values for every row.  If you want to group by the Name to roll the results up, use the `SUM()` and you'll get one row per unique name combination

```
create table Test ( Name varchar(10)
,idmanga int
,idauthor int 
,idgenre int 
,idmagazine int)

insert into Test
select 'Roger',1,2,3,4
union select 'Bob',4,5,6,7
union select 'Roger',8,9,10,11
union select 'Bob',12,13,14,15
union select 'Bill',16,17,18,19

select Name
, idmanga+idauthor+idgenre+idmagazine
from Test

select Name
, SUM(idmanga+idauthor+idgenre+idmagazine)
from Test
group by Name
```

Comment: I mean sum like idauthor(1)+idmanga(2)+idgenre(3)+idmagazine(4)=10

Comment: While I don't think the original query is what the author is after, please don't specify `VARCHAR` without also specifying the length. This is lazy shorthand that will lead to trouble at some point. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx